# We've made it to public beta!

Tags: discussion

Good work everyone, we've clearly demonstrated the viability of this site!

And keep at it! There are lots more great questions to be asked and answered, and lots of people to invite now that it's that little bit easier, just sending them a link.

Answer (score 11):

### Awesome!

Miscellaneous random things we need to take into account and think about in the upcoming days:

- We're probably going to get a bunch of new users who don't know much about the site. Let's be teachers when it comes to the pieces of the scope we've fleshed out so far.
- In terms of content rate, this might be the danger zone. Now that the excitement of private beta is over, it's possible that folks might stop being active, and we could lose users. Let's keep content - *good* content - coming, and make sure we don't rely on an influx of new folks to keep the site going.
- We're not done yet, which is why I'm happy but not celebrating. The site *looks* like it can succeed, but only time will tell. I'm honestly slight worried about activity levels, but hey, the amount of data we've got is pretty slim.
- Let's try and help the mods. We'll have some pro-tem mods soon, presumably, but we have to keep community moderation constant and strong.

We're absolutely still a work in progress - and a site always is - but we're getting better.